# EXcel VB "Cant'f find project or library"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm desperate.

I keep getting this message EVERY time I now press the F9 (calc) key :(((((  Can anyone help me resolve it?

MY model is essentially a number processor with a VB shell around it which uses VB to help the user navigate it and the shell has no sexy code such that you use and probably the most sophisticated bit of coding adds and removes in-cell menus.

I have checked the "references" in the VB project and none say "MISSING:..."

The error only occurs when I press F9 - not when I press Shift+F9 and only on the current model - not (so far) in any another models.  All macros appear to work and calculation does continue.  I have been using this model for many months and this error has just crept in.

Any help much apprciated.

Thanks,

E

Answer (score 0):

Read the suggestions in this ExcelKey post, at http://www.excelkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2654

Hope that resolves your issue